# (C) Bit shifting/char placement in a short int variable

Tags: c, hex, byte

New to C.

The overall goal here is to put a character in a short int, and have it occupy the left byte of the short int rather than the right byte. To elaborate -

I'm trying to take a variable:

```
unsigned short int packager;
```

(short int is 2 bytes.)

and put this char in it:

```
unsigned char temp = A;
```

(A in binary is 01000001.)

So, how is this done? What I want the short int to look like is this:

0100 0001 0000 0000

My current idea is to work in hex values. If I could say something like 
`packager = 0x(temp)` or 0x(temp) and append a 0? (idk..) and then use shifting or masking.. I might be able to get somewhere. The biggest roadblock seems to be my inability to use a variable to make a hex value. Again, the overall goal is to put a character in a short int, and have it occupy the left byte of the short int rather than the right byte.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to describe it "as a hex value". A number is a number. Binary, decimal, octal and hex are all representations of that number for humans to use (e.g. we only use hex because it nicely maps onto nibbles). When you get down to it, they're all represented the same way within the computer.

Comment: If you want to do bit frobbing, better use `unsigned` variables (some operations aren't defined for signed variables). For lots of fun twiddling bits, look at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
packager = A << 8
```

Note that speaking of left and right bytes is a bad habit.  Instead use high and low.  Left and right may be interpreted by some as dependent on address order and hence endianess (unless you really want something to do with address ordering).

Comment: wow, it worked! can you explain to me what's happening here? I would think that it wouldn't work, because A is only a char (1 byte), so it's shifted in place 8 times, and it would end up being 0000 0000. But somehow it shifts into another byte as 0100 0001 0000 0000? And THEN it's assigned to packager?

Comment: Whilst I kind of agree about "high and low" vs. "left and right", note that they are the "left-shift" and "right-shift" operators as far as the standard is concerned...

Comment: The char is promoted to an int before the shift in this expression, which is why it doesn't overflow.